# Delphi - how to address a tool in after running the program

Tags: delphi

I want to know if there is a way to address a tool which I put in my form after the program is executed? For example:

Suppose there are 100 label components in a form and you put an edit box in your form and ask the user to enter a number in the edit. When the number is written in the edit, the label with the same number will change the font colour.

But you cannot code it before running the program and need sth like this:

```
Label[strtoint(edit1.text)].color:=clblue;
```

But as you know this code does not work. What should I write to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like you demonstrate, you just need to store the form’s controls into some type of array or list.

Sorry, I currently do not have access to my Delphi IDE, but I think I can give you an overview to what you need to do.  I will also provide a link that better demonstrate the concept.

Here are the steps:

First ensure your controls have a consistent naming format that includes an index number in the name.

Example: Label1, Label2, . . . .

Next you need to store the controls into some type of an array or TList.

Example:

```
Var
ControlList : TList
. . . . 
ControlList := TList.Create;

. . . .

{ Load the controls into the list after they been created }
ControlList.Add (Label1)
ControlList.Add (Label2)
ControlList.Add (Label3)
```

Here an alternatives to adding the Labels to the list manually.

```
for I := 1 to 3 do
begin
    ControlList.Add(TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+IntToStr(I)));
end;
```

Now designate some event handler where you will put the code to update the label.  This handler routine will first convert the user inputted value to an integer.  Them use that value as an index to the control array.  Once you have the label designated to be updated, set whatever properties you like.

```
idx := StrToInt(InputBox.Text);
lbl := TLabel( ControlList[idx])
. . . . 
lbl.Color := clBlue;
```

Check out this link [Control Arrays in Delphi](http://shawkie.tripod.com/dd96046.htmhttps://) for a more detailed description.

**-- Update --**

Although my previous answer would work, Remy Lebeau comment give me an idea to a better approach.  You do not need to store the controls in an array or list, just use the Findcomponent() command to locate the control.  Below are two examples demonstrating this concept.

**Example using an Edit box OnKeyPress event:**

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
    LabelControl : TLabel;    
begin

if ord(Key) = VK_RETURN then
  begin

    LabelControl := TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+Edit1.Text));
    if (LabelControl <> nil) then
       LabelControl.Color := clblue;

    Key := #0; // prevent continue processing of the WM_CHAR message
  end;

end;
```

**Another example using a Button's OnClick event:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    LabelControl : TLabel;
begin
    LabelControl := TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+Edit1.Text));
    if (LabelControl <> nil) then
    begin
        LabelControl.Color := clBlue;
    end;
end;
```

**Things to note about the code:**

- In the first example, for the label to be updated, the user must press the enter key after inputting the desired label number.
- In the second example, the user must press a button after entering
  the number of the label to be updated.
- In In both examples, invalid responses are ignored.

Comment: Thank. What you have said works but I want to avoid coding for each component. In your example there were only 3 labels , that's ok but what about for 100 labels?

Comment: When populating the list/array, you can use the Form's `FindComponent()` method in a loop, eg: `for I := 1 to 100 do begin ControlList.Add(TLabel(FindComponent('Label'+IntToStr(I))); end;`

Comment: Remy Lebeau, that is a very good suggestion.  I gave you +1 and included it in my answer.

Comment: @Mentat that is not how I suggested to use `FindComponent()`. Doing the find on every key press is way overkill. Do the search one time and cache the results in a list/array instead. Also, your check of the `ClassType` should be using the `is` operator instead, if at all since you know beforehand that you are searching for `TLabel` controls only.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, You are right, I tweak your idea which I think is correct, but not necessary.  Review the code again.  You will see that the only code that is being executed every time a key is pressed is the IF condition.  The logic that contains the FindComponent() method is only executed when a valid Label control is found.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I agree, using the IS operator makes the code easier to read and the check itself is not necessary.  I remove it from the examples.

Comment: @Mentat In your `OnKeyPress` example, `FindComponent()` is being called *every time* the ENTER key is pressed, and in your `OnClick` example `FindComponent()` is being called *every time* the button is clicked.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I am not sure If I understand what your point is.  The behavior you describe is correct and directly answers the question presented.
In example one, when the user presses the ENTER key, in the designated Edit box, the code should execute the Label logic if a label control is found. Same thing for Button logic.  Once the user enters a value in the designated Edit box, he can then press the designated button to execute the Label logic.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you right, all the Labels already contain a number in their caption.

Then, you could use the Controls array, that already exists in TForm, which contains all controls that belong to the form:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    // ...
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;
  // ... 
{    uses
              System.RegularExpressions;
}
        // ...

        procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);

          {
          // if aLabel.Name instead of aLabel.Caption 
          // will work for Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4 ...
          function TryNameToInt(AName: string; var ANumber: Integer): boolean;
          var
            aRegEx: TRegEx;
            aMatch: TMatch;
            aStr: string;
          begin
            aStr := '';
            ANumber := -1;
            aRegEx:= TRegEx.Create('[A-Za-z_]+([0-9]+)');
            aMatch:= aRegEx.Match(AName);
            if aMatch.Success then begin
              aStr := aMatch.Groups.Item[1].Value;
            end;
            Result := TryStrToInt(aStr, ANumber);
          end;}

        var
          aControl: TControl;
          aLabel: TLabel;
          aNumberEdit: Integer;
          aNumberLabel: Integer;
          aIdx: Integer;
        begin
          if TryStrToInt(Edit1.Text, aNumberEdit) then begin
            for aIdx := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do begin  // Controls is the list of all Controls in the form, ControlCount is the length of this list
              aControl := Controls[aIdx];
              if aControl is TLabel then begin // this gets only TLabel controls
                aLabel := TLabel(aControl);

                if TryStrToInt(aLabel.Caption, aNumberLabel)
                    {or TryNameToInt(aLabel.Name, aNumberLabel)} then begin
                  if aNumberLabel = aNumberEdit then begin
                    aLabel.Font.Color := clBlue;
                  end
                  else begin
                    aLabel.Font.Color := clWindowText; // if needed
                  end;
                end;
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
```

Comment: `aControl.InheritsFrom(TLabel)` should be `aControl is TLabel`, there is no need to call `TryStrToInt(Edit1.Text, aNumberEdit)` on each loop iteration, and `TryStrToInt(aLabel.Caption, aNumberLabel)` should probably be looking at the label's `Name` instead of its `Caption` (`Label1`, `Label2`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FindComponent` function to do that:
Here I dropped a TButton and TEdit on form, you type the Label number you want to change the font color in Edit and then press the Button. Write this code in `OnClick` event for the Button:

```
Var
  mColor: TColor;
  mLabel: Tlabel;

begin

  mColor := clGreen;

  mLabel := FindComponent('Label' + Edit1.Text) as TLabel;

  if mLabel <> nil then
     mLabel.Font.Color := mColor;

end;
```

or if you don't want to press the Button and want it as you type in Edit, you have to write the code in `OnChange` event for Edit.